# Is it possible for a gtk_menu_item to act like a button and throw a signal for a callback?

Tags: button, gtk, signals, menubar

I have a gtk_menu_bar and one of the gtk_menu_item must, instead of dropping down a submenu, throw a signal for a callback. Is this possible?
I have tried adding a gtk_event_box, but the menu bar doesn't accept it for it's not a menu item; and connecting a signal to that menu item, but with no success.

Thank you!

Comment: hum... connecting an "activate" signal to the menu item, will actually throw the event, but after pressing it twice..

Comment: Could you clarify when exactly you are expecting the signal? As soon as the  menu item is highlighted or on mouse click or selection using keyboard?

Comment: @another.anon.coward I'm expecting the signal on mouse click (just like a normal button, as I stated on the title). thks

Comment: hmm did you try connecting `button-press-event` signal?

Comment: Excelent @another.anon.coward, 'button-press-event' worked. Please post it as answer so I can accept it :) thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure why `activate` signal is triggering on a double-click (maybe I didn't get that part of the problem right) but as `GtkMenuItem` *is a* `GtkWidget` it is possible to get mouse click events by connecting to `button-press-event` / `button-release-event` signals.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PS: with `button-press-event`, the menu "button" didn't get focused and the GUI would go directly to the window. I didn't try the `button-release-event`, but, if this works, I suppose that this might be the most indicated for this case. Anyway this is only a suposition.